# Returns distinct record in a joins query - Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, select, join, activerecord

I'm trying to get and display an order list including the current status.

```
@orders = Order.joins(order_status_details: :order_status)
               .order('id DESC, order_status_details.created_at DESC')
               .select("orders.id, order_status_details.status_id, order_statuses.name, order_status_details.created_at")
```

It works good but is returning all the rows with order ids duplicated like this:

```
+----+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
| id | status_id | name                 | created_at          |
+----+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
|  8 |         1 | Pending              | 2016-01-31 16:33:30 |
|  7 |         3 | Shipped              | 2016-02-01 05:01:21 |
|  7 |         2 | Pending for shipping | 2016-01-31 05:01:21 |
|  7 |         1 | Pending              | 2016-01-31 04:01:21 |
+----+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

The correct answer must return uniques ids, for the example above should be the first and second row.

I was already trying with `distinct on select`, `.distinct`, `.uniq` and `.group` but I'm getting an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I believe your model is "An `Order` has many `OrderStatusDetail`". So that is the reason why you have several different `name` in your result.

So you can modify the query like this:

```
    @orders = Order.joins(order_status_details: :order_status)
                   .order('id DESC, order_status_details.created_at DESC')
                   .where('order_status_details.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM order_status_details GROUP BY order_id)')
                   .select("orders.id, order_status_details.status_id, order_statuses.name, order_status_details.created_at")
```

Ideally, the `where` condition is used for selecting just the expected id of `order_status_details`, I use `min_id` for example, you can modify it as needed

Comment: This looks simple but I can't find a solution :/

Comment: @AlejandroAraujo: Hmm, I just updated the answer, pls check it out

Comment: I modified your solution a little. I changed MIN to MAX to get the current status, not the first. Correct this If you want to accept your answer as correct `.where('order_status_details.id IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM order_status_details GROUP BY order_id)')`